# main() not executing, but compiling

Tags: c++, compilation, runtime

I have this simple program:

```
// Include libraries

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// Include locals

// Start

#define NUMBER 600851475143

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    long long int ans = 0;
    long long int num = NUMBER;

    vector<int> factors;

    do
    {
        // Get lowest factor

        for (int i = 1; i <= num; ++i)
        {
            if (!(num % i))
            {
                factors.push_back(i);

                num /= i;
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (num > 1);

    cout << "Calculated to 1.\n";

    int highestFactor = numeric_limits<int>::min();

    for (int i = 0; i < factors.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (factors[i] > highestFactor)
        {
            highestFactor = factors[i];
        }
    }

    ans = highestFactor;

    cout << ans << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

compiling with `g++  -O2 -c  -o prob3.o prob3.cpp` proved successful, but when I ran it I saw nothing and it just kept running and I had to Ctrl-C (force-kill) it in the end. When I try to add

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    cout << "Test\n";
```

to the program, `Test` didn't get printed too. It's like my program is not executed at all.

Any help or advice is appreciated!

## Solution

I forgot prime numbers started at 2. Change `for (int i = 1` to `for (int i = 2`.

Comment: Do you see it as running in your task manager/ps ?

Comment: Your compile command won't produce an executable, just an object file. Do you have a link step as well?

Comment: Try `cout << "Test" << endl;` `endl` flushes the stream, which for once (i.e., it's rare) is a good thing to do.

Comment: @FredLarson yes I did. It was in the makefile.

Comment: @ihsoyih: Ok, I just wanted to make sure it wasn't a silly build issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those nested loops are going to loop forever. The inner `for` loop will only ever execute once because of the `break` so it will only ever do `num /= 1`. That means `num` never decreases and so `num > 1` will never be false. I suppose you just need to wait longer!

The reason you're not seeing "Test" is probably because you haven't flushed the output. Try:

```
std::cout << "Test" << std::endl;
```

Comment: @ihsoyih I updated. It's not just taking a long time, it's taking forever.

Comment: @ihsoyih just change the `1` in the inner loop to a `2`.

Comment: Thanks guys! I updated `1` to `2`. I forgot prime numbers start at 2 :P

Answer (score 2):

Your program is simply running. It takes a long time to execute.

For the `cout << "Test\n";`, it's a matter of the `cout` stream not being flushed: what you wrote to the stream is still in your program memory and not yet flushed to the system to be printed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to start your for condition from 2? The module function doesn't have sense if start from 1.

if (!(num % i))

Num / 1 give 0, so you're not enter in the if condition

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is an infinite loop. The first factor you find is 1 (since `num % 1` is `0`) and as such you divide `num` by `1` which results in `num` which re-enters the for loop, which does the same again and again.

Also with this fixed (initialize `i` in the loop with `2`), your inner for loop is most likely an infinite loop and/or causing UB. Otherwise (as the others stated) it is "just" running very long. For the case where it is different (assuming most common platforms here). This depends on the value you are trying to factor, if the first factor is smaller than `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` then this does not apply. Lets call those primes `BIGPRIME` (`600851475149` would be a good example).

`long long int` is at least 64bit in size. `int` is unlikely to be bigger than 32bit on most platforms, so when it is not bigger on your platform it can only go up to `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` which is (again assuming the common 32bit platform here) `2147483647` which is in turn promoted in the comparison to `long long int` but keeps its value, which is always smaller than `BIGPRIME`. Always increasing `i` does never get anywhere, and once you are at `max()` you enter UB land as signed integers don't wrap in C++. Your code might infinite loop there, or do some things like recording `-1` as a valid factor, or make you pregnant.

You can easily observe that by adding some

```
if( 0 == (i%100000000)){ std::cout << i << std::endl; }
```

into the `for` loop.